# set build to successful when there are only known errors

Tags: unit-testing, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a YAML-pipeline that builds my code and runs some tests. My code-base is pretty huge and full of weird legacy-code that fails my unit-tests. This is why I want to track only new errors within my code, while those legacy-errors should be ignored.

```
- script: "nunit3-console.exe" MyAssembly.dll
  displayName: 'Run unit-tests'
  failOnStderr: false
  continueOnError: true
```

When executing that script I get a partially successful build, because the exit-code of nunit is 5:

[image: task run unit-tests]

As I want only new errors to make the build fail, I also implemented a quality-gate:

```
- task: BuildQualityChecks@8
  displayName: 'Check for test-errors'
  inputs:
      checkWarnings: true
      warningFailOption: 'build'
      warningTaskFilters: '/^Run unit-tests$/i'
      warningFilters: |
          /\d+\) Error :/i
          /\d+\) Failed :/i
```

However the entire build stays "partially successfull" because of the previous task. Is there any way to ignore the outcome of the `Run unit-tests`-task, as I manage them within the quality-gate ayway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the exit-code for your script-task:

```
- script: |
    "nunit3-console.exe" MyAssembly.dll
    exit 0
  displayName: 'Run unit-tests'
  failOnStderr: false
```

Now that task allways succeeds. Notice that I also ommited the `continueOnError`-property, as the task never produced any error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by calling it from python.

```yaml
- script: python -c "import os; os.system('nunit3-console.exe MyAssembly.dll'); print('FINISHED')" 
  displayName: 'Run unit-tests'
  failOnStderr: false
  continueOnError: true
```

This task just succeeds, also when there are errors.